# How do I use third-party OpenAI API services？

Tags: api

The address of my request is not the official website of Openai, but another address. In the preferences of the software, I only found the key, I need to change the request address until I am? Please tell me where the specific configuration file is, or where can I configure it?[image]

I want to configure my base URL.
Since the request format for OpenAI is URL + key, but you only provided the option for key, I want to know where I can configure the URL.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I want to configure my base URL. Since the request format for OpenAI is URL + key, but you only provided the option for key, I want to know where I can configure the URL.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica StackExchange! If you need to make HTTP requests to a custom site, simply use [`HTTPRequest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HTTPRequest.html). You don't need Wolfram Connector for that.